# What is the favored discriminant analysis package in R?

Tags: r, discriminant-analysis

I have been using the LDA package for R, but it is missing quite a few features especially those that can assess the output.

Are the any preferred packages that have some of the following?

- Univariate Test Statistics
- Canonical Analysis
- Multivariate Statistics like Wilk's lambda